# ReflectionTestUtils.setField - TypeMismatchException

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, reflection

I am trying to test a Spring service method, setting a private variable annotated with @Value via 'ReflectionTestUtils.setField' method.

Code:
`@Value("${temp-files-delete-time}") private int deleteTime;`

Test:
`ReflectionTestUtils.setField(someService, "deleteTime", 1);`

When it try to run it I get:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`

`org.springframework.beans.**TypeMismatchException**: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${temp-files-delete-time}"`.

The variable I am trying to set is an int as well as the value I am using in the reflection method. Am I missing something ?

Comment: You should probably reconsider if reflection is really the way you want go. If you use constructor injection instead of field injection you can set up your bean very easily in a test through the constructor. Alternatively, you can write a Spring powered test and set the property with `@TestPropertySource`.

Comment: What is the value of `${temp-files-delete-time}` ? Rather than an issue with `ReflectionTestUtils`, it appears that the value is a `String` but you are expecting it to be an `Integer`.

Comment: @drumonii I thought that might be the case, but I am not sure why. I set the value in my application.yaml file like this `temp-files-delete-time: ${TEMP-FILES-DELETE-TIME:24}`. When I test the code manually it works fine.

Comment: @Henning I will look into using `@TestPropertySource`. Thanks

Comment: @Gustav if you set `temp-files-delete-time` in your application.yaml as `temp-files-delete-time: 24`, it should work

Comment: @drumonii yes but I need to keep it in the format I mentioned above because that allows me to override the value in the application.yaml with one from an environment variable, and at the same time set a default one. That way has worked for me in other cases, and in this one as well. It is just when I try to set the value in the test that it fails and I can not understand why.

Comment: @Gustav Understood but that notation is actually not necessary. Spring boot will override the `24` value with the value of the `TEMP-FILES-DELETE-TIME` environment variable if set. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config for how SB prioritizes different forms of configuration values. Therefore I would recommend setting it as `temp-files-delete-time: 24` in your application.yaml which will be the default. Then in a deployment env for example you'd set the `TEMP-FILES-DELETE-TIME` environment variable to another value

Comment: @drumonii great, I did not know that. I will take a look into it. Thanks